# Swift error - *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift

Trying to implement sign in/sign up features but I can't get it to work. I can sign in fine, but when I try to sign up the app crashes and I get the following error.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Project3.SignUpViewController logInPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa6d5432b90'

This is my code within the sign-up view controller:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func signInPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) {
            (user, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Registration Unsuccessful \(error!)")
            } else {
                //successful
                print("Registration Successful")

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMenu", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you connected the action with

```
@IBAction func logInPressed(_ sender: Any)
```

and copied the vc and renamed to

```
@IBAction func signInPressed(_ sender: Any)
```

so either disconnect the old `@IBAction` and connect the new or leave the name of it as it is but change the inner code according to the vc ( sign in/up ) but this will mislead your code as function names should be descriptive